# How to configure a neural network to selectively change only certain characters in a string?

Tags: neural-networks, natural-language-processing, applications

I'm trying to figure out how to train a neural network to macronize Latin text.
Essentially, in Latin, vowels can either be long or short, and length is indicated with a macronized character: i.e. o is short, ō is long. Most advanced texts don't mark vowel length, which can be an issue because vowel length determines pronunciation and word meaning: liber means book, līber means free, for example.

Is there any way to train a neural network to replace only vowels in a word while contextually evaluating it as part of a larger sentence? I've tried training an RNN many-to-many model to map unmacronized text to macronized text, but it ends up being incredibly inefficient and inaccurate because an unmacronized word can map to *any* macronized word. Ultimately, the only characters in each word that should ever change are the vowels, and even then only to their macronized counterparts: liber can be liber, līber, libēr, or lībēr only.

There is an abundance of training data in the form of parallel macronized and unmacronized text. This feels like a simple question but I've been unable to find any resources specifically detailing how to implement this. Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap each RNN cell in a custom module that is an identity for consonants (output = input when the input is a consonant) and predicts the macronization of vowels (it outputs the result from the RNN cell when the input is a vowel).

And it should always return the hidden state of the RNN cell so that each cell connects to the next cell for any input.